# jQuery navigation slides

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, navigation, slider

I have a `div` slider that works fine, but I want a navigation that indicates the current active slide and if you click on a link it shows the slide that you clicked on. My problem is, whenever I click on a link from the nav my page becomes unresponsive and i need to close the tab and reopen the website.I tried it in many browser and it does the same thing. Something went wrong when I added the "navSlides" on click event.Can someone explain me what i need to do to make it work ? Thanks !

Here is my [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/fm95wc4k/1/)

```
 contentSlides = $('.slide-wrapper');
    navSlides = $('#slide-nav > ul > li > a');
    slidesLeng = contentSlides.length - 1;
    index = 0;

    for (i = 0; i <= slidesLeng; i++) {
        $(contentSlides[i]).addClass('slide-' + i);
        $(navSlides[i]).addClass('slide-' + i);
    }    

    $('div.slide-wrapper > span').on('mouseover', function () {
        $(this).css({ 'font-size': '40px' });
    });

    $('div.slide-wrapper > span').on('mouseout', function () {
        $(this).css({ 'font-size': '50px' });
    });


    $('.next').on('click', function () {
        if (index != slidesLeng) {
            $(contentSlides[index]).fadeOut(400, function () {
                $(this).removeClass('active');
                $(navSlides[index]).removeClass('active');
                index++;
                $(contentSlides[index]).fadeIn(400).addClass('active');
                $(navSlides[index]).addClass('active');
            });
        }
    });

    $('.prev').on('click', function () {
        if (index != 0) {
            $(contentSlides[index]).fadeOut(400, function () {
                $(this).removeClass('active');
                $(navSlides[index]).removeClass('active');
                index--;
                $(contentSlides[index]).fadeIn(400).addClass('active');
                $(navSlides[index]).addClass('active');
            });
        }
    });

    $(navSlides).on('click', function () {
        var slideClass = $(this).attr('class');

        $(contentSlides[index]).fadeOut(400, function () {
            $(this).removeClass('active'); 
            index = 0;
            while (slideClass != $(contentSlides[index]).attr('class') || index<=slidesLeng) {
                index++;
            }
            contentSlides[index].fadeIn(400).addClass('active');
        });    
    });
```

Comment: What do you mean by "page crashes" ? Did you test on many browsers? please elaborate

Comment: The page becomes unresponsive and i need to close the tab and reopen it . Yes i tried it in all browsers , It does the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the `while` loop in the click handler never exits. The expression `slideClass != $(contentSlides[index]).attr('class') || index<=slidesLeng` is always true, because the comparison is done between the class property of each element. These will not be the same because the content slides have additional classes, like `slide-wrapper`.

So, the class property of the first slide will be `"slide-wrapper active slide-0"`, but the class property of the first link will just be `"slide-0"`.

This can be remedied by using the [jQuery index function](https://api.jquery.com/index/) to get the index of the element instead of trying to match the classes. A working version of the click handler is as follows. An updated, working version of the JSFiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/kbkkg4ev/.

```
$(navSlides).on('click', function () {
    var slideIndex = navSlides.index(this);

    $(navSlides).removeClass('active')
    $(this).addClass('active');

    $(contentSlides[index]).fadeOut(400, function () {
        index = slideIndex;
        $(this).removeClass('active');
        $(contentSlides[index]).fadeIn(400).addClass('active');
    });
});
```